# Limiting depth of shortest path query using Gremlin on JanusGraph

Tags: graph, gremlin, shortest-path, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I have a fairly large graph (currently 3806702 vertices and 7774654 edges, all edges with the same label) in JanusGraph. I am interested in shortest path searches in it. Gremlin recipes mention this query:

`g.V(startId).until(hasId(targetId)).repeat(out().simplePath()).path().limit(1)`

This returns path that I know to be a correct one immediately but then hangs the console (`top` shows janusgraph and scylla to be processing stuff furiously though, so I guess it's *working* in the background, but it takes forever). It does the right thing and returns first (correct) shortest path if used like this:

`g.V(startId).until(hasId(targetId)).repeat(out().simplePath()).path().next()`

I would like to limit this query so that gremlin/janusgraph stops searching for path over, let's say, 100 hops (so I want max depth of 100 edges basically). I have tried to use `.times(100)` in multiple positions but if `.until()` is used with `.times()` in the same query it always crashes with a NullPointerException in gremlin traversal classes, ie:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.TraversalHelper.hasStepOfAssignableClassRecursively(TraversalHelper.java:351)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.strategy.optimization.RepeatUnrollStrategy.apply(RepeatUnrollStrategy.java:61)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversalStrategies.applyStrategies(DefaultTraversalStrategies.java:86)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.applyStrategies(DefaultTraversal.java:119)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:198)
        at java_util_Iterator$next.call(Unknown Source)
...
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I apply such limit? I need this to return first result or fail, fast.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another break condition in your `until()` and also make sure to `limit()` the result before you ask for paths:

```
g.V(startId).
  until(__.hasId(targetId).or().loops().is(100)).
    repeat(__.both().simplePath()).
  hasId(targetId).limit(1).path()
```

Calling `tryNext()` on this traversal will give you an `Optional<Path>`. If it's empty, then no path was found within the given distance.