# Search path in gremlin upto a given distance

Tags: python, path, gremlin, janusgraph

I want to find path(s) between 2 vertices until either I find the path or the distance exceeds a given value (say 10).

For an example, say a graph `(A)->(B)<-(C)<-(D)<-(E)->(F)<-(G)<-(H)->(I)`. And maximum distance is 4. So if I search for a path `(A-E)`, I get `ABCDE`, but if I search `(B-G)`, I would get `"too far away"`.

I currently use this for finding path(s) between 2 vertices : 
`g.V(nodeID1).repeat(__.both().simplePath()).until(__.hasId(nodeID2)).path().limit(limit).toList()`

By the way, I'm doing this using gremlin_python

I found this question ([Limiting depth of shortest path query using Gremlin on JanusGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528738/limiting-depth-of-shortest-path-query-using-gremlin-on-janusgraph)), that would have helped me. But it isn't answered yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add another break condition in your `until()`:

```
g.V(nodeID1).
  repeat(__.both().simplePath()).
    until(__.hasId(nodeID2).or().loops().is(eq(4))).
  hasId(nodeID2).limit(limit).path().toList()
```

If the list is empty, then no path was found within the given distance.

---

Python edit :

```
g.V(nodeID1).
  repeat(__.both().simplePath()).
    until(__.hasId(nodeID2).or_().loops().is_(P.eq(4))).
  hasId(nodeID2).limit(limit).path().toList()
```